# How to use multiple deadline_timers?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I'm setting up 2 boost asio deadline_timers. The first is to start immediately, while the second I'd like to be able to turn on and off when needed. My understanding is that I only need to use a single io_service object for multiple timers.

The problem is, timer_A is calling callback_a() immediately as if it doesn't have any work to do.

I create io_service and give it a work object in the constructor.

```
class TestClass
{
    std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::deadline_timer> timer_A;
}

TestClass()::TestClass 
{
    io = std::make_shared<boost::asio::io_service>();
    work = std::make_shared<boost::asio::io_service::work>(*io);
    // ...
}
```

Then I start timer_B immediately, but only create timer_A. I haven't given timer_A an expiration time yet, so it's not active.

```
TestClass()::operator()() 
{

    timer_B = std::make_shared<boost::asio::deadline_timer>(*io,
        boost::posix_time::seconds(30));
    timer_B->async_wait(boost::bind(&TestClass::callback_b, this,
        boost::asio::placeholders::error));

    timer_A = std::make_shared<boost::asio::deadline_timer>(*io);

    std::unique_ptr<std::thread> io_thread =
        std::make_unique<std::thread>([&] { io->run(); });

    // ...

    while (running) {
        // ...
    }

    io->stop();
    io_thread->join();
}
```

Later during run-time, I call this function and give it an expiration time expecting it will expire 10 seconds from the time called.

```
TestClass::called_later()
{
    timer_A->expires_at(timer_A->expires_at() +
        boost::posix_time::seconds(10));
    timer_A->async_wait(boost::bind(&TestClass::callback_a, this,
        boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    // ...            
}
```

The problem is that timer_A expires immediately because I see it calls callback_a immediately.

Anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: what is timer_ack?

Comment: Provide MCVE. Why are you creating `io_thread` as local variable?  Where is `join` on this thread?

Comment: @SeanF - sorry, typo, fixed it.

Comment: @rafix07 - I've edited to show the join. io_thread is only to be run for TestClass which itself is a thread.

Comment: Your timer A expire 10 seconds after its own previous expire time, when there was no previous expire time, so who knows what that does

Comment: Correct, there is no previous expire time because it's just being setup, and not activated. Is that not the correct way to handle it?